# how to avoid page refresh when user types in invalid form input

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a simple "contact me" section on my website and I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the page on refreshing when a user enters in an invalid email. Reason why I want to prevent this is because when they enter in an invalid email the page refreshes and brings them to the top of the page. I have an error that displays what the user missed but they have to scroll back down to the contact section to see it. I'm not sure how to go about preventing the page from scrolling to the top after they submit. All I have right now is a simple php form validation. Any suggestions? would this be done with JavaScript? or can I add this to my existing php validation script? not sure where to start. thanks!

Side note i am using PHP for form validation.

FIXED! To prevent the page from going back to the top i removed `"index.php"` from my form action:

before

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

after

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

now the page does not refresh and does not go to the top of the page.

Comment: that's where submit event handler event prevent default is used

Comment: @JaromandaX is this something i can add in my php file?

Comment: It cant be simple if you have to scroll to see the whole bit

Comment: no, PHP can't handle client events

Comment: I may have misunderstood your intentions though. Is it your intention to validate the data and only submit the data if the validation passes?

Comment: @RohitGupta the contact section is at the bottom of the main page. it does not cover the whole page.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes and i should mention that i have a PHP script to validate the data before it submits and that works perfectly fine but if a person puts in an invalid email the page refreshes and puts me at the top of the page (where i cannot see the form until i scroll down) then i can see the alert that i entered an invalid email.

Comment: Found my solution here. thank you everyone! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559607/php-focus-on-input

Comment: Had this issue using ASP.NET, I didn't add the `method="POST"`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by an invalid email.  If you are referring to the format then something like this is what you should be using, and the browser will check the email for you.

```html
        <label for='idEmail' class="required">Your email address</label>
        <input type='email' name='inpEmail' id='idEmail' class='full_width'
         maxlength='100' autocomplete='email' value=''>
```

The critical bit is making the input as type `email`

Comment: im using PHP to validate all the data and puts an alert below the input if its incorrect or missing but for the email if it is not correct the page refreshes and puts me at the top of the page. im trying to find a way to prevent the page from refreshing if the email field is input incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The commenter above means

```
e.preventDefault().
```

```
     const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("you just clicked the button").
     }
    
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
         <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit}>Click Me</button>
    </form>
```

Including that e.preventDefault() keeps the page from reloading.

//Edit
Tried to paste in code from a site, but SO is giving me a hard time about the formatting. It was my first ever website so it's not the prettiest. Here is the link to the GitHub: https://github.com/LazAustin/AldenForCongress/blob/main/contact.php

Lines 1-66 are the PHP code.
Line 192 is where the form body starts (JS and Bootstrap).
Line 251 is some JS code to check for inputs.

Hope this helps

Comment: can i use this and have it check to see if the input field is input correctly and if it is then submit?

Comment: The `type` property sometimes will. Especially for `type=email`. Or you can write if if statements to check there is input or even incorrect input. I'll edit my response right now to include an example from a PHP contact form from one of my websites.